# Slice the top of a cone

Tags: modeling, workflow, objects

So I just started working with Blender 2.6 and the two books I have don't really discuss how to modify objects other than "here's edit mode..."

What I have is two cylinders with one slightly smaller than the other and protruding out of the larger one.  I need to "fillet" from the larger cylinder to the smaller one.  I decided to create a cone with the same diameter as the larger cylinder which then protrudes through the smaller one giving the illusion that the larger cylinder is reducing to the size of the smaller one.  Of course the problem is that the cone continues through and extends beyond the smaller cylinder.  My thought was to just cut a section off of the cone that lies inside the smaller cylinder.  Unfortunately my two books don't really cover doing anything like that.  So any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

Use vertex bevel in edit mode.

To do that:

1. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode.
2. Right click the top vertex to select it.
3. Use vertex bevel (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) and use your mouse to adjust the bevel amount:

   [image]
4. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to exit edit mode.

Comment: Okdoke, that worked really well.  Had to play around a little to figure out exactly what you were doing but now that I know it's easy enough to do.  Thanx!

Answer (score 6):

There are more than ten ways of doing this. Since you just want to make fillet in-between, you may also consider this way:

1. Select the two loops you want to connect;
2. <kbd>W</kbd> > Bridge Edge Loops;

[image]

PS: In this case, the two cylinders have to first be become a single mesh, if not yet (J to join them).

Answer (score 4):

it's probably best to do this with normal modeling:

1. Add a cylinder <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Add > Mesh > Cylinder*
2. Switch to *Edit mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
3. Select the top part of the cylinder with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd>*> Box select*:

   [image]
4. Scale it down <kbd>S</kbd>:

   [image]

[image]

Or, if you want all three sections to be part of one object:

1. Add a circle:

   [image]
2. Extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>)  upwards:

   [image]
3. Extrude inwards:

   [image]
4. Extrude upwards again:

   [image]
5. Select the second edgeloop from the top and move it up on the Z axis (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>):

   [image]

However, if you actually want to slice the cone apart, you can use the *Bisect* tool or a *Boolean modifier*.

Comment: In the first example you selected the top of the cylinder using a box select.  For some reason I can't seem to do a box select on a cylinder.  I can do it on a plane and a cube but not a cylinder.  Any idea why?  A lot of projects I'm interested in doing will revolve around cylinders - thanx!

Comment: @user1572 What happens when you try? You can also select the top edge loop with `Alt`+`RMB`.

Answer (score 4):

For your specific problem, modeling as described above is probably the best solution. However, there is some nice new functionality in Blender which should not be kept secret...

Blender has just gotten a "Slice the top" function. It's called "Bisect".

In edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) do the following:

1. Select all faces with <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Space</kbd>*> Search* and enter "Bisect" in the search field that appears, or press the *Bisect* button in *3D view > Tool shelf*.
3. Draw the bisection line.
4. In the tool side panel (the left one in the 3D view, which you can toggle via <kbd>T</kbd>), check "Fill" and "Clear Inner" (or "clear outer"), and you have cut a slice away.

[image: The tool options for bisect]

For better precision, enter numerical values (for example *Plane Normal* xyz = `0.0`, `0.0`, `1.0` will give you a horizontal cutting plane.)

Comment: Ah, this saved my day ! +1